# regex number expression

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

After years of sponging knowledge from the SO community, I'm here to ask my first question.

I'm trying to create a regex expression for a JavaScript web project to find a whole number (positive or negative) with a thousands separator, or just a whole number, in a given string.

Some valid examples:

```
561,085 
3,894,320 
-59,099 
1,000 
1000 
-1000 
1 
-1 
0
```

Invalid examples:

```
-01
01393
01,300,00
-04,044
```

I've created this expression so far:

```
\b(?:[0])|(?:(((-)?[1-9]?\d{2}|\d)((,)?\d{3})|((-)?[1-9]+\d*)))\b
```

(?:[0]) - match a leading 0

|(?:(((-)?[1-9?\d{2}|\d)((,)?\d{3}) - or match a 1-9 starting number with a comma and 3 digits after

|((-)?[1-9]+\d*))) - or just match a whole 1-9 starting number without any commas

I think it works in all cases except for when I test a string with 5 digits trailing a minus sign, for example like so: 
Value: -01110

In this case it accepts 01110 as a match.

Could anyone help me figure out what I've gotten wrong with the expression? 
Also would not mind some general pointers/feedback on how I popped the ask-a-question-cherry here, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:0|-?[1-9]\d*|-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})+)$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XSTEO3/1).

---

That means:

```
^                             # start of the string
(?:                           # open par
    0                         # zero
    |                         # or
    -?[1-9]\d*                # -100 or 234 or -121323232
    |                         # or
    -?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})+ # separated by comma
)                             # close par
$                             # end of the string
```

To actually use it "in the wild" (that is in any given text), you need to adjust the anchors to lookarounds:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?:0|-?[1-9]\d*|-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})+)(?=\s|$)
# ^^1^^                                              ^^2^^
```

`^^1^^` means "either the start of the string or some whitespaces in front of the expression", `^^2^^` means "either some whitespaces or the end of the string right after the expression".

See another [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/99TMQB/1).

Comment: This is great! The expression is more neat than mine, too. I replaced "^" with "\b" to make it look through a given string, I'm assuming it will not produce any odd side effects? Thank you for your reply! -Edit: I need at least 15 rep to upvote your answer, will return later and upvote, haha

Comment: I'd would not use `\b` here, see https://regex101.com/r/aFvsFT/1 in comparison to https://regex101.com/r/2gWiyL/1 (the one at the end of the answer). Btw., you can accept answers which helped you (green tick on the left).

Comment: I don't think javascript supports `\Z`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @PoulBak: You're right, thanks for spotting it. I always test it in `PCRE` first.

Comment: @Jan gotcha! using your adjusted string now and it's perfect. accepted your answer, cheers